# Downloading files from telegram using api

Tags: python, telegram

There is a question, how to download new files or all files from a channel using python and telegram api?

And how to make the script using api detect new files?

I googled for information, but didn't find any information on this topic

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some Telegram client module, e.g. [Pyrogram](https://docs.pyrogram.org/).

To be able to interact with the API you'll have to [authorize](https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/auth) first. After that [handle update](https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/updates) and check whether a [message](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/Message#pyrogram.types.Message) contains images and then [download](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/download_media) them.